# How to move and jump with SKSpriteNode at the same time

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction, game-development

Currently I have jump and move working with two buttons. They are SKSpriteNodes and I have caused each action to occur when they are touched. The problem I am facing is when I press one button the action works and when I press the other button, the other action stops because the button is no longer touched. I am trying to allow the user to move and jump at the same time. For example, hold the left button and press the jump button.

```
 // MARK: Touches
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let pointTouched = touch.location(in: cameraNode)
        if leftArrow.contains(pointTouched)
        {
            leftArrow.alpha = 0.5
            moveWizard(moveBy: -300, forTheKey: "moveX")
            wizardRunAnimation()
            wizardCharacter.xScale = -1
        }
        if rightArrow.contains(pointTouched)
        {
            rightArrow.alpha = 0.5
            moveWizard(moveBy: 430, forTheKey: "moveX")
            wizardRunAnimation()
            wizardCharacter.xScale = 1
        }
        if attackButton.contains(pointTouched)
        {
            attackButton.alpha = 0.5
            wizardAttackAnimation()
        }
        if upArrow.contains(pointTouched)
        {
            upArrow.alpha = 0.5
            jumpWizard(forTheKey: "jumped")
            jumpWizardAnimation(fortheKey: "jumpedAnimation")
        }
    }
}
func alpha() {
    leftArrow.alpha = 1
    rightArrow.alpha = 1
    attackButton.alpha = 1
    upArrow.alpha = 1
}
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let pointTouched = touch.location(in: cameraNode)
        if leftArrow.contains(pointTouched)
        {
            wizardCharacter.removeAction(forKey: "moveX")
        if rightArrow.contains(pointTouched)
        {
            wizardCharacter.removeAction(forKey: "moveX")
        }
        if attackButton.contains(pointTouched)
        {
            wizardCharacter.removeAction(forKey: "wizardRun")
        }
        if upArrow.contains(pointTouched)
        {
           wizardCharacter.removeAction(forKey: "jumped")
        }
    }
```

Comment: please fix your spacing

Comment: I meant make everything lined up neatly, not add a line between functions

Comment: From what you posted here, everything acts as a tap, nothing is being held.  Your character can move both left and right at the same time, which is probably causing your problem.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I am trying to jump and run, pressing the left arrow and the up arrow at the same times, is there a way I can detect a hold from touches? Or must I use gestures ?

Comment: If you just hit right and let go, your character is still going to move right.  you need to remove actions on touchesEnded.  Also, left and right should not be separate keys

Comment: I do that already, Im sorry I should of posted this code as well. I just need help with the problem I stated, I do not know how to hold the (left or right button) and allow the user to tap the jump button as well. To allow the character to move left or right and jump.

Comment: well change your question to reflect that

Comment: obviously you are removing all actions instead of doing the exact same thing you are doing in touches begin, and I am predicting this without even having to see the important part of your code that you so conveniently left out.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon not removing all actions, I use a key to remove the action. I just edited my code, check it out.

Comment: You are doing exactly what I predicted.  You are checking where your touch began, why are you not checking where your touch ended

Comment: @Knight0fDragon ok, how do I fix it?

Comment: ..... do exactly what you are doing in touches began.  When you develop your skills a little better, you will need to figure out what to do when a finger slides off of a button instead of releasing off of a button.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon is there  a way to get the last touch ? For examples: if leftArrow.contains(lastTouch) && jumpArrow.contains(pointTouched) { do jump and move action } ?

Comment: Just do exactly what you are doing in touches begin, but i stead of starting the action, stop it

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Thank you for your help, I figured it out... Is there any way you can explain the touchesEnd function more. Im trying to understand but I cant wrapt my head around it yet.

Comment: It is the exact same function as touchesBegan, except instead of the moment your finger hits the screen it is the moment your finger leaves the screen